# multiple updateSelectizeInput from filtered dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, reactive

This one has me really going around in circles.

I am working on an R script that loads a dataframe and uses fields from the dataframe to populate a hierarchical set of `selectizeInput`. E.g. each of the inputs represent a subset of what is in the previous. Each SubRegion contains multiple LCC’s, Each LCC contains multiple ENB’s, and so on.

When the user select a value in any of the inputs, that value will used to filter the dataframe and all of the other selectizeInputs need to be updated from the filtered data.

It seems to work fine for the first input (SubRegionInput) but every time I try to get it to respond to and/or filter by any of the others (e.g. add `input$LCCInput` to the observe block) they get populated for a few seconds and then go blank.
I suspect the answer is quite simple and/or I am doing something really dumb, but I am a total hack with no formal R training so am probably missing something quite basic (if so sorry).

Below is a partial chunk of code (sorry I can’t include it all but this is for work and I can’t share the details of what I am doing).

NOTES
The current outputs are just so I can see what is going on while I develop this portion of the code.
I know right now it is only set up to filter on the one value…everything I have tried to do it on more has failed so I included the most functional code I have so far.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("KPI DrillDown"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   fluidRow(
     selectizeInput("SubRegionInput", "SubRegion", SubRegionList ,selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
     selectizeInput("LCCInput", "LCC", LCCList,selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
     selectizeInput("ENBIDInput", "ENBID", ENBIDList,selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
     selectizeInput("SiteNumInput", "SiteNumber", SiteNumberList,selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
     selectizeInput("SiteNameInput", "SiteName", SiteNameList,selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
     selectizeInput("LNCELInput", "LNCell", LNCellList,selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
     selectizeInput("SectorInput", "Sector", SectorList,selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),

      mainPanel(
         #plotOutput("distPlot")
        verbatimTextOutput("SubRegionText"),
        verbatimTextOutput("LCCText"),
         verbatimTextOutput("view")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output) {


  observe({
    input$SubRegionInput
    temp <- SiteInfo[SiteInfo$SITE_SUB_REGION %in% input$SubRegionInput, ]
    thisLCCList = sort(temp$BACKHAUL_LCC[!is.na(temp$BACKHAUL_LCC)])
    updateSelectizeInput(session = getDefaultReactiveDomain()
                          , inputId = "LCCInput"
                          , choices = thisLCCList
                          , selected= NULL)
    thisENBIDList = sort(temp$ENODEB_ID[!is.na(temp$ENODEB_ID)])
    updateSelectizeInput(session = getDefaultReactiveDomain()
                         , inputId = "ENBIDInput"
                         , choices = thisENBIDList
                         , selected= NULL)
    thisSiteNumberList = sort(temp$SITE_NUMBER[!is.na(temp$SITE_NUMBER)])
    updateSelectizeInput(session = getDefaultReactiveDomain()
                         , inputId = "SiteNumInput"
                         , choices = thisSiteNumberList
                         , selected= NULL)
    thisSiteNameList = sort(temp$SITE_NAME[!is.na(temp$SITE_NAME)])
    updateSelectizeInput(session = getDefaultReactiveDomain()
                         , inputId = "SiteNameInput"
                         , choices = thisSiteNameList
                         , selected= NULL)
    thisLNCellList = sort(temp$SECTOR_NUMBER[!is.na(temp$SECTOR_NUMBER)])
    updateSelectizeInput(session = getDefaultReactiveDomain()
                         , inputId = "LNCELInput"
                         , choices = thisLNCellList
                         , selected= NULL)
    thisSectorList = sort(temp$Sector[!is.na(temp$Sector)])
    updateSelectizeInput(session = getDefaultReactiveDomain()
                         , inputId = "SectorInput"
                         , choices = thisSectorList
                         , selected= NULL)
   output$view<- renderPrint(temp)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have access to your data, I used mtcars as an example. 
To begin with, since you have so many filtering, I would suggest creating a search or update button, which is what I did in my codes. I only did one filtering using dplyr after extracting all the selectizeInputs. I have to manually change all the empty searching parameter to select all in order to avoid filtering to NA.

Overall, I think the problem with your code was you are observing too many updateSelectizeInputs at once. I did try to recreate using your way, and what I ended with was that I could only update single selectizeInput, and the other selectizeInputs were not selectable.

Hopefully, this method fits your data.

Codes:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

data <- mtcars
SubRegionList <- unique(data$cyl)
LCCList <- unique(data$gear)
ENBIDList <- unique(data$am)
SiteNumberList <- unique(data$vs)
# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("KPI DrillDown"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    fluidRow(
        selectizeInput("SubRegionInput", "SubRegion/cyl", SubRegionList ,selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE),
        uiOutput("LCCInput"),
        uiOutput("ENBIDInput"),
        uiOutput("SiteNumInput"),
        uiOutput("Search"),

        mainPanel(
            verbatimTextOutput("view")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    SiteInfo <- data
    # temp <- ""
    observe({
        if (!is.null(input$SubRegionInput)){
            subRegionSelected <- input$SubRegionInput
            ## Create a temp dataset with the selected sub regions.
            temp <- SiteInfo[SiteInfo$cyl %in% subRegionSelected, ]

            ## Push the newly created selectizeInput to UI
            output$LCCInput <- renderUI({
                selectizeInput("LCCInput", "LCC/gear", unique(temp$gear), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
            })
            output$ENBIDInput <- renderUI({
                selectizeInput("ENBIDInput", "ENBID/am", unique(temp$am),selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
            })
            output$SiteNumInput <- renderUI({
                selectizeInput("SiteNumInput", "SiteNumber/vs", unique(temp$vs), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
            })
            output$Search <- renderUI({
                actionButton("Search", "Search")
            })

            ## Function that linked to the actionButton
            display <- eventReactive(input$Search,{
                temp <- SiteInfo[SiteInfo$cyl %in% input$SubRegionInput, ]
                # ## manually change all the empty searching parameter to select all in order to avoid filtering to NA
                LCC <- input$LCCInput
                if (is.null(input$LCCInput)){LCC <- unique(temp$gear)}
                ENBID <- input$ENBIDInput
                if (is.null(input$ENBIDInput)){EBVID <- unique(temp$am)}
                SiteNum <- input$SiteNumInput
                if (is.null(input$SiteNumInput)){LCC <- unique(temp$vs)}

                ## Dplyr::filter data
                temp <- temp %>% 
                    filter(gear %in% LCC & am %in% ENBID & vs %in% SiteNum)
                temp
            })

            ## Run the actionButton
            output$view <- renderPrint({
                display()
            })

        } else {
            ## Display waht the data looks like when no Sub Region is selected 
            output$view<- renderPrint(data)
        }
    })


}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated, this gives me some ideas on how to proceed. Exactly how the reactivity actually works is still something I am struggling to wrap my head around.
I will need to work out some additional details. For example the data selection needs to be hierarchical. For example the user will select the first level (e.g. cyl) and the selection of the subsequent levels will be based on seeing the results of the previous selections. So the search button is a workable option but I would like to avoid it if possible.
Thanks again!